# How to create a proper mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm still new to programming. I have created a mysql database. And i'm connecting to it in my java app using local host link like this:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DataTest?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false", "root","password");
```

However, I want my java program to be able to connect to my database on any device.

What should I do? how can I make this happen?

Comment: You can build that connection string like you would build any other string. Like `"jdbc:mysql://" + whateverStringWithHost + ":" + port + ...` etc...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the connection string like below

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","root","root");

For more details, you can read the oracle docs from the below link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html